# Why can't I get the JS object value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

Sooo, it looks like I don't know what I'm doing.

I thought I was making a object array:

```
$.each(oldList, function( key, item) {
    self.items.push([{
             "name": $(item).data('name') ,
             "id": $(item).data('id') ,
             "lat": $(item).data('lat') ,
             "lng": $(item).data('lng') ,
             "index": key
    }]);
});
```

Then I do this:

```
$.each(self.items, function( key, item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

And the result is this:

[image]

But when I try to do this `console.log(item.name);` I just get *`undefined`*.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(item[0].name);` should work.

Comment: As the results showing, the `item` is an array, not an object. The answer point out that you push an array to `self.items`, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing an array which contains an single item to `self.items` instead of pushing an object.

```
$.each(oldList, function( key, item) {
    self.items.push({
             "name": $(item).data('name') ,
             "id": $(item).data('id') ,
             "lat": $(item).data('lat') ,
             "lng": $(item).data('lng') ,
             "index": key
    });
});
```

So in your second each loop `item` is an array with one item, not an object so `item.name` is undefined, but you can use `item[0].name` to access the name(without changing the `push` code)

Comment: Huh... I'm not sure what's happening, but I **really** thought I  tried that after looking at this tutorial: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/

Comment: @Steven there is difference between `push([{` and `push({` (between pushing array, consists of one object, and pushing object).